# I want to create search function in Android

Tags: android, json

I am able to search in Android for first search but after back is pressed in editbox then search will not work ID does not display second search result.

Please solve my issue. Result function are giving me search result:

```
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parentAdapter, View view, int position,
                                long id) {


            // We know the View is a <extView so we can cast it
            TextView clickedView = (TextView) view;

            Toast.makeText(Search.this, "Item with id [" + id + "] - Position [" + position + "] - Planet [" + clickedView.getText() + "]", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
    Runnable r2 = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            finish();
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
        }
    };
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            finish();
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
        }
    };
    // we register for the contextmneu
    registerForContextMenu(listView);

    // TextFilter
    listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    ev1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                                  int count) {
            pw.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            System.out.println("Text [" + s + "] - Start [" + start + "] - Before [" + before + "] - Count [" + count + "]");
            if (count < before) {
                // We're deleting char so we need to reset the adapter data
               // listView.setAdapter(null);
                //adapter.resetData();
                adapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }



        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                      int after) {
            ;
        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            searchre = ev1.getText().toString();
            results();

        }


    });
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            searchre = ev1.getText().toString();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + searchre, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            //listView.setAdapter(null);
           // results();


        }
    });

}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

That's simply because you don't *search* if text is deleted. Remove following if statement

```
if (count < before)
```

and always call

```
adapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Thank you..but my problem is when i search second time list does not empty and also not showing  the result...am confused ..first search are ok .please help me...

Comment: Well, so did you try removing "if (count < before)"?